# Explanation required for duplicate self.subscription

Tags: rosbag2

Can someone please explain what the purpose of the 2nd `self.subscription` line is for?

https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/blob/d6030c4c26443c87a094c3091c3cd2059da3816d/rosbag2_examples/rosbag2_examples_py/rosbag2_examples_py/simple_bag_recorder.py#L39-L44

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on a different page: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html

> prevent unused variable warning